# Why my android develop app default language is Chinese?

Tags: android

I am developing my android app . And my default strings.xml is English like this:

default strings.xml:
[image: default strings.xml]

And I have went to my phone Setting to set language is English(United States)

However , when I run my app , it always show Chinese:

[image]

I use these code to get some information:

```
  Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

it shows the locale value is "zh" , but my phone system language is English at the same time.

Comment: what's your system language when your app's language is Chinese?

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp It's English(US)

Answer (score 0):

Open menu=>Setting=>Language& Keyboard=>Select Locale=>set any locale from this

Comment: Excuse me , that is what I have done . Whatever language I have choice ， it always show Chinese. Except when I use code to change my app language.I want my app follow the system language if the user doesn't use my app function to change language which I support.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android do you use? Is it Android N(above lollipop)? Android N allows the user to configure a list of languages. If the first language is not supported, and the second is Chinese, then you will get Chinese UI (if Chinese strings are available, of course).

It seems to me that your first language is not supported on your mobile and your second one is chinese. So thats why

Comment: It's android 6.0.But I found that other apps can change to English . It's so weird for me.

Comment: I use these code to get some information:

      Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

it shows the locale value is "zh" , but my phone system language is English at the same time.

Comment: thats strange. which android phone you are testing on?

Answer (score -2):

Push `語言` to change the phone's language settings.